# Select The Row Position Togther With The Entire Row

Tags: mysql

I've got this part complete to return the row position in a select that a particular row would return in a part of an order clause.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        @i:=@i + 1 n, id
    FROM
        1_packages, (SELECT @i:=0) q
    ORDER BY group_id , position , pack_description) j
WHERE
    id = 10;
```

I would also like to return the rest of the columns together with its position. I presume it's an INNER JOIN but I can't figure the syntax.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Can you please add table structure, example data and expected output.

Comment: delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `1_package_group_eit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rows` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

Comment: Please add that as an edit to your post, not an unreadable comment

Answer (score 1):

Just include the columns in the subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*, @i:=@i + 1 as n
      FROM 1_packages t cross join
           (SELECT @i:=0) const
      ORDER BY group_id, position, pack_description
    ) t
WHERE id = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax. The row is returned with an extra column giving it's select position.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *, @i:=@i + 1 n
    FROM
        1_packages, (SELECT @i:=0) q
    ORDER BY group_id , position , pack_description) j
WHERE
    id = 10;
```